# Angular - Scroll to the top with href="/"

Tags: angularjs

I have a `<a href="/">` link on the logo on my home page.

In Angular, if I'm at the the bottom of my homepage, clicking on this does nothing. On other pages it does the take my to the homepage.

What I want if its clicked from my homepage and I'm at the bottom -  is for it scroll to the top.

I'm using `<ng-view autoscroll="true"></ng-view>` - assumed this would do the trick.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I think because you are not actually changing the location, the `href="/"` does not trigger `ng-view` to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

What about assigning your first element at the top of your page with `id="top"`, and then do:

```
<a href="/#top">Go to Top</a>
```

Comment: But then what if its clicked from another page (the logo is placed in the header which sits on all pages).

Comment: if you make the link on your logo in header like: `<a href="/" id="top">` then you can put a `<a href="/#top">` link anywhere to return to top of home page